# FFmpeg or GStreamer for command line conversion of audio files?

Tags: command-line, sound, ffmpeg, gstreamer, transcode

I think I'm mixing up and I need some one to clarify things for me!

What is the differences between GStreamer and FFmpeg.
What I need is a command line to convert file(s) from one format to another.

I know I can do that with installing ffmpeg but I read and I saw allot of talk about Gstreamer.
Can I use it the same way?

If yes, which one is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GStreamer is a multimedia framework used from within applications. It is not generally used directly from the command line.

FFmpeg also has a set of libraries for use within applications but is mainly known for the `ffmpeg` command. This program can transcode media files and seems more suitable for what you want to do.

To find out how to use ffmpeg, read [`man ffmpeg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ffmpeg).